# Dropbox Sync API errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have downloaded and installed the Dropbox Sync API for Android from here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync

I couldn't understand much of their tutorial. It lacked a lot of crucial variables, so that I had to find them out myself. I now have a very messy code and a lot of things aren't there.

```
private DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;
static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;  // This value is up to you // thanks for telling what it actually does, Dropbox!
DbxPath path = new DbxPath("/test.pdf");


public void onClickLinkToDropbox(View view) {
    mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount()); // try /catch error

            DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open(path); //try/catch error
            String contents = testFile.readString();

            Log.d("Dropbox Test", "File contents: " + contents); // try / catch error

        } else {
            // ... Link failed or was cancelled by the user.
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This gives me errors on the 3 lines, saying that I need to add try/catch.
But when I add try/catch, Eclipse tells me to null the variables, which would mean all the functions would only read nulls, thus not reading anything..

Could anyone help me any further? Dropbox only confused me more by giving wrong instructions etc. I am sure that even if I didn't have 3 try/catch errors it would still not work.

Anyone here who has experience with the Dropbox Sync API and could share an example program reading a txt file in a User's Dropbox folder?

Bart

Answer (score 0):

For more info on `REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX`, check out the Android documentation for `onActivityResult`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent). It's there to help you differentiate between different activities.

For a working example, I'd suggest looking at the `HelloDropbox` example that comes with the SDK. Among other things, it reads a string from a file in Dropbox.

Here's the relevant code from `HelloDropboxActivity.java`:

```
try {
    // ...
    DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());
    // ...
    String resultData;
    DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);
    try {
        resultData = testFile.readString();
    } finally {
        testFile.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried looking at the hellodropbox example, but it instantly crashed, and it could only be due to the use of a dropbox API function. (I checked the whole code and could not find any bug) I have decided to quit trying to use the API in my app.